# Lost: Defining a function which takes a tuple of numbers and returns the sum of only the even numbers in the tuple

Tags: python, polymorphism

Title pretty much says it all. This is the code I wrote that I've been tinkering around with.

```
def sum_evens(tup):
    for num in tup:
        if num % 2 ==0:
            total = num+num
            print(total)
```

I'm pretty lost here, any ideas on what I can do? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,filter(lambda x:not x%2,tup))`

Answer (score 1):

you need to start total at 0 and add to it when you find matching numbers

```
def sum_evens(tup):
    total = 0
    for num in tup:
        if num % 2 ==0:
            total = total+num
    return total
```

finally you need to return the total to whatever called it so it can be used

there are lots of better ways to do this ... but I just edited your function to work

```
print sum_evens([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # 2+4+6 = 12
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but the evens are added in the order of their occurrences. Just changed that in the comments.

Comment: lol ok :P I know what order it does it ... i should have just put 12 :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about list comprehensions. Basically, they are backwards for loops such that you can define a new list by iterating over an old list. You can also add a conditional clause to pick and choose.

In this scenario, we loop through an existing tuple and look for the individual members with a remainder of zero when divided by two. We then construct a list with these members and find a sum.

```
print sum([x for x in my_tuple if x % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: no ... sum is a builtin in python ... suprisingly enough it sums numbers

Comment: Trevor, `sum` is a built in function which takes an iterable.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm wondering why this was tagged polymorphism.

Comment: I think he meant polynomial maybe... but even thats a stretch ... trevor might be a better one to ask that of (I think my code in the comment is best anyway :P)